# exemple of a simple application to practice monitoring and logging

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, devops, monitoring

I'm trying to learn monitoring and logging, so to be able to learn those skills, I need a simple web application that generate logs.

URL to some github or gitlab repo will be so helpful

Comment: Feel free to use https://github.com/taleodor/mafia-deployment

Comment: thanks, I'm wondering if this app uses a database or not

Comment: It has redis for persistence, not using an sql database.